# How put Array in API DEFINITION WSO2

Tags: wso2, openapi, publisher

Can someone help me please ?
"RefeItem": [
{
"Key": "dev",
"Value": "dev234"
}
]
how can i set this in API Definition publisher wso2

Answer (score 0):

Latest versions of WSO2 API Manager supports ***Swagger 3.0.0 OpenAPI*** definitions. So any swagger definition adhering to that standard is supported.

You requirement can be achieved using the following snippet,

```
responses:
    200:
        description: Success
        content:
            application/json:
                schema:
                    $ref: '#/components/schemas/RefeItem'

components:
    schemas:
        RefeItem:
            type: array
            items:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/keyValueObj'
        keyValueObj:
            type: object
            properties:
                Key:
                    type: string
                Value:
                    type: string
```

You can find more information on using array data types in swagger [here](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/data-types/#array)